Convert the rows data into columns by grouping and the column names from row values
My Table code as follows,
CREATE TABLE SalesData (
    ID INT,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    Year INT,
    SalesAmount DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO SalesData (ID, ProductName, Year, SalesAmount)
VALUES
(1, 'ProductA', 2021, 150.00),
(2, 'ProductB', 2022, 200.00),
(3, 'ProductA', 2022, 300.00),
(4, 'ProductB', 2021, 400.00);

and my expected result is
| ID | Product_Year | ProductB_Year | ProductA_SalesAmount | ProductB_SalesAmount |
| -- | ------------ | ------------- | -------------------- | -------------------- |
| 1  | 2021         | 2022          | 150                  | 200                  |
| 2  | 2022         | 2021          | 300                  | 400                  |

Should I use pivot to achieve this and do we have any other method like cross apply ?

And have you tried anything at all? Where did you get stuck?

Pivoting is aggregating, so the solution is no different to the other 100's of duplicates out there.
